# What meaning does the にあって have in this phrase?

Tags: meaning, usage

> 神秘の力が幽霊にあって現世に介入していたとしても、不思議はないんじゃないかと

As far as I can understand

Noun + にあって has the meaning of

> In (time / location indicator)
>
> At  (time / location indicator)
>
> On (time / location indicator)
>
> Due to / because

However in this case it's neither time or location nor a reason

I would roughly translate it to

> As for the ghost even if it has a mysterious power that allows him to intervene in the present world I don't think that's strange

What do you think ?

Comment: Would changing the order help?「 幽霊に神秘の力があって....」

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a verbatim translation is "a mysterious power exist in the sprite and he excuses the power..."
にあって sounds literary.

Comment: `sprite` `excuse(s)` -> Maybe you meant to type "spirit" "execute(s)", no..?

Answer (score 3):

あって seems to be simply the te-form of the verb ある.

神秘の力が幽霊にある
There is a mysterious force in ghosts.

The te-form is used just to connect the clauses.